# an issue when trying to call a function that have an out parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a function like this :

```
example(long a,long b,string c,DateTime d,DateTime e,out decimal f)
```

when i am trying to call it i am doing this :

```
long a =1;
long b=2;
string c="";
DateTime d=DateTime.Now;
DateTime e=DateTime.Now;
decimal f=0;

example(a,b,c,d,e,f) --> Here is giving me the error : the best overloaded method has some invalid argument
```

can you please help me fix this problem

Comment: the right way to call your function is example(a,b,c,d,e,out f);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `example(a,b,c,d,e, out f);`

And there is no need to initialize `f`, and it is better not to do so (it's misleading):

```
//decimal f=0;
decimal f;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `d` is an [`out` parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645764%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) you need the [`out` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (in C#):

```
example(a, b, c, d, e, out f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `out` keyword in your method call as well:

```
example(a, b, c, d, e, out f);
```

See also: [out parameter modifier (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `out` keyword also when you calling your method like;

```
example(a,b,c,d,e, out f);
```

From [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx);

> The out keyword causes arguments to be passed by reference. This is
>   like the ref keyword, except that ref requires that the variable be
>   initialized before it is passed. **To use an out parameter, both the
>   method definition and the calling method must explicitly use the out
>   keyword.**